# Sort by resolved property in HotChocolate

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, hotchocolate

Is it possible to sort by a resolved property in HotChocolate? A resolved property can be an arbitrary expression, even some LINQ expression, which I set up in an `ObjectType<T>`-derived class:

```
descriptor
    .Field("MyResolvedField")
    .Type<StringType>()
    .IsProjected(false)
    .Resolve((context, ct) => 
    {
        //definition goes here
    });
```

I tried to set up a `SortInputType<T>`-derived class and on the `Configure` method explicitly mention my resolved field as:

```
descriptor.BindFieldsExplicitly();
descriptor.Field("MyResolvedField");
```

But this always fails with an exception.
Is this even possible at all? If so, how?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?  I'm facing this problem as well.

Comment: No, I wasn’t. Didn’t pick it up again.

Comment: Haven't tried this yet but check out https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/discussions/3209

Comment: The issue still persists, and the solution is very bad.
Why would I require a field handler for a plain simple field that returns an integer?